# htaccess 403 not work custom page

Tags: .htaccess

my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request sent by the browser includes login1.php...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} login1\.php
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php


# Then you just need a generic rule to rewrite /mysite into login1.php
RewriteRule ^mysite$ login1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
```

When I try to access the page: `http://example.com/login1.php` I get an error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /login1.php on this server.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

but I want to display message on page `404.php`

Comment: Notice this part of your error message: "Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." Check your Apache error log to see what's causing the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are looping because once you issue forbidden once for `/login1.php` it keeps on throwing `403` since `%{THE_REQUEST}` doesn't change.

Have your rules like this to fix it:

```
RewriteRule ^404\.php$ - [L,NC]

# If the request sent by the browser includes login1.php...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (index|login1)\.php
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Then you just need a generic rule to rewrite /mysite into login1.php
RewriteRule ^mysite$ login1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
```